# Python myqsl.connector connection error on pyton.org

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection

I have a mysql server on my computer. I did port fowarding on my modem. I checked port is open or not with signal sites and return success answer. When i try connect on my pc with host = "localhost" i returned success answer. But when i try connect mysql server with python.org's shell, i returned connection error same like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py”, line 529, in open_connection
self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/init.py”, line 177, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py”, line 104, in init
self.connect(**kwargs)
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py”, line 781, in connect
self._open_connection()
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py”, line 284, in _open_connection
self._socket.open_connection()
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py”, line 531, in open_connection
raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘myipadress:3306’ (111 Con
nection refused)
```

How can i connect my mysql server ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to encounter this error first do the following:

1. Make sure the host is in the format `127.0.0.1` and there are no `/` or `\` in the host name
2. Check if you have specified all the correct info about the server like passwords, user, root, etc
3. Make sure the server is active and there is no fire wall blocking your access
4. Remove all the unwanted users from the server